# How do I specialize member functions based on the base class of the templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize member functions of a template class based on the type of template. In particular I'd like to have specializations based on polymorphic types. I've been struggling with the syntax. Here is my try which obviously produces the error: two or more data types in declaration of `doSomething()`

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:

  void doSomething();

};

template<>
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type
void MyClass<T>::doSomething() 
{
    // Do something with Derived type
}

template<>
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value &&
                       !std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type
void MyClass<T>::doSomething() 
{
    // So something with Base type
}

template<>
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type
void MyClass<T>::doSomething() 
{
    // Do something with all other types
}
```

Compilation gives..

```
error: two or more data types in declaration of 'doSomething'
```

BTW, I did get the following to compile, but the specialization did not work as expected at runtime. Base and derived types end up going through the non-specialized version of `doSomething()`.

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public base {};

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:

  void doSomething()
  {
       // Do something for non-specialized types
  }    
};

template<>
void MyClass<Derived>::doSomething() 
{
    // Do something with Derived type
}

template<>
void MyClass<Base>::doSomething() 
{
    // So something with Base type
}
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Always post the full error message in your question.  Oh, and your program isn't even syntactically valid on the first line.  Is this your actual code you're compiling?  Post your actual code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've fixed the code to the best of my knowledge. I've also added a previous attempt, that does compile but ends up not working as intended.

Comment: Your second example that  you claim does not work as intended works just fine.  Please be a lot more specific.  What behavior did you intend and what did you observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specialize `doSomething` simply because it's not a template. `MyClass` is a template and you can specialize the class, each specialization having one `doSomething`. If that's not what you want then you need to make `doSomething` template overloads and, for the SFINAE to work, the SFINAE check must be done on the `doSomething` template parameter, not on the `MyClass` parameter. Lastly your checks are wrong.

So here is my version:

```
template<class T> struct MyClass
{
    template <class U = T>
    auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, U>
                                   && !std::is_base_of_v<Derived, U>>
    {
        foo_base();
    }

    template <class U = T>
    auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Derived, U>>
    {
        foo_derived();
    }

    template <class U = T>
    auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Base, U>>
    {
        foo_else();
    }
};
```

And here is a battery of tests:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
class A : Base {};
class B : Derived {};
class X {};
```

```
auto test()
{
    MyClass<Base>{}.foo();      // foo_base
    MyClass<Derived>{}.foo();   // foo_derived
    MyClass<A>{}.foo();         // foo_base
    MyClass<B>{}.foo();         // foo_derived
    MyClass<X>{}.foo();         // foo_else
}
```

And of course I must mention the C++17 clean solution:

```
template<class T> struct MyClass
{
    auto foo() 
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<Derived, T>)
            foo_derived();
        else if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>)
            foo_base();
        else
            foo_else();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked more or less. However, I just had to adjust the _v syntax. My version reads...
std::enabled_if_t<std::is_base_of<Derived, U>::value>  instead of std::is_base_of_v.

Comment: @Shammi yeah, that's c++14 I guess

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution pass through a `ForFoo` template class, that define a `foo()` method, with a couple of specializations for `Base` only and `Derived` classes. So `MyClass<T>` can inherit from `ForFoo<T>`.

I mean... if you define a `ForFoo` set of template classes as follows

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct ForFoo
 { void foo () { std::cout << "other type" << std::endl; } };

template <typename T>
struct ForFoo<T,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
                        && ! std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type>
 { void foo () { std::cout << "Base type" << std::endl; } };

template <typename T>
struct ForFoo<T,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type>
 { void foo () { std::cout << "Derived type" << std::endl; } };
```

`MyClass` simply become

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass : public ForFoo<T>
 { };
```

The following is a full working C++11 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
class A : Base {};
class B : Derived {};
class X {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct ForFoo
 { void foo () { std::cout << "other type" << std::endl; } };

template <typename T>
struct ForFoo<T,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
                        && ! std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type>
 { void foo () { std::cout << "Base type" << std::endl; } };

template <typename T>
struct ForFoo<T,
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value>::type>
 { void foo () { std::cout << "Derived type" << std::endl; } };

template <typename T>
struct MyClass : public ForFoo<T>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   MyClass<Base>{}.foo();      // Base
   MyClass<Derived>{}.foo();   // Derived
   MyClass<A>{}.foo();         // Base
   MyClass<B>{}.foo();         // Derived
   MyClass<X>{}.foo();         // other
 }
```